# What is the best way to call an external function on the DOM element rendered by a React stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm still relatively new to React, and I'm not really using it in a typical way.

I'm working on a library of functional components (UI components), and I have no state or store or anything.

I have an external function which accepts an HTMLElement (DOM element) as the only parameter. For the sake of argument, let's say that this function initializes the passed DOM element as a Carousel (and let's say the function is referenced under `Carousel.init()`).

I also have a functional component, `Carousel`, to render my carousel elements:

```
const Carousel = ({ slides, ...props }) => (
    <Module {...props}>
        {slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <Component name='slide' key={index}>{ slide }</Component>
        ))}
    </Module>
);
```

Which essentially just outputs static HTML. I need to call `Carousel.init` on the DOM element this outputs, and I need to call this function in the same file that the component is declared in (and naturally, multiple instances of the component by be included on the page).

The two biggest clues I have found on my quest for an answer are [React ref's](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), and [ReactDOM's `findDomNode` method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode). These clues led me to this discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936

At the bottom of this discussion, you can see a [comment from myself](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936#issuecomment-403468065) explaining my issue, and showing the solution I currently have (which works, by the way):

```
const Carousel = ({ slides, ...props }) => (
    <Module ref={node => Carousel.init(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node))} {...props}>
        {slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <Component name='slide' key={index}>{ slide }</Component>
        ))}
    </Module>
);
```

This seems *super* hacky to me, I don't think I've come across any example using both `refs` *and* `findDomNode`. Is there a more appropriate, or even a recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required to make use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` because the `ref` that you have attached is on a React component and not the DOM element within the React component. If you pass a `ref` on to the DOM node within Module, you can avoid using `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`

```
const Carousel = ({ slides, ...props }) => (
    <Module innerRef={node => Carousel.init(node)} {...props}>
        {slides.map((slide, index) => (
            <Component name='slide' key={index}>{ slide }</Component>
        ))}
    </Module>
);
```

And in Module

```
class Module extends React.Component {
   render() {
      <div ref={this.props.innerRef}>
           {/* other relevant code */}
      </div>
   }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, this helps a lot. Will experiment when home and accept your answer if all good.